# How do I make the modal fully scrollable when the virtual keyboard is shown?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, mobile-safari

I'm using bootstrap 4 to build a modal with a form. I use the example of a scrollable modal from [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content).
The issue is that the keyboard on ios devices overlaps the bottom part of the modal and scrolling doesn't scroll all the way down when the first text input is in focus.
I can't understand how do I resize .modal class properly to take into account virtual keyboard size.

Demo: https://vadimblv.github.io/demo/

```
<div class="modal fade" id="openModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
          aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Contact</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="contactfname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <!-- Other inputs-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Modal with ios keyboard][2]

How do I make the modal fully scrollable when the virtual keyboard is shown?

Comment: Seems to be a specific mobile browser issue, what mobile browser are you using? Because on Chrome and Safari iOS it works fine, the modal scrolls

Comment: I'm using Safari for iOS. Modal scrolls all the way down if the keyboard is not shown.